# To implement follow unfollow functionality with one to many relationship on same table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, one-to-many, code-first

I have a User class which stores user's details like Id, Name etc.

**Now, every user can follow or unfollow other user.So, should i generate a new table Follow with columns Original_Id and Follow_Id where Original_Id is the user's own Id and  Follow_Id is the foreign key to User's table pointing to Id primary key**.

Two possibilities i am seeing here:

1>Follow table would have one to one relationship with User table through Original_Id column.

2> Follow table would have many to one relationship with User table through Follow_Id column.
So, if you have a user named Newton that has two followers, Tesla and Edison, your Users table will have something like this:

- Id, Name
- 1, Newton
- 2,Tesla
- 3, Edison

and my Follow table will have following values:

- Original_Id, Follow_Id
- 1, 2
- 1, 3

Is this approach correct. what i am thinking is possible, if any better approach please suggest me?
Will it be possible to filter User's related data from other tables through this Follow table.
I am showing here sample relationship of User's class with other class:
[image]

Now, i want to show user's only those post from user's whom he is following.
Any guidance most appreciated.

Comment: From a dim and distant memory, yes this is how you should do it. I seem to think they are called "link tables", although whether that is an "official"/ correct term or just one we used I am not sure.